# non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;

Tags: java

i get this warning for below code:
non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter; how i can fix it?

```
 private static boolean checkImpled(Class interfaceClass, Class<?> forName) {

        try {
            if (!Modifier.isAbstract(forName.getModifiers())
                    && !forName.isInterface()
                    && interfaceClass.isAssignableFrom(forName)
                    && !interfaceClass.equals(forName)
                    && forName.getConstructor(null) != null) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // false
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: At what line do you get this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the constructor without parameters, you should call `forName.getConstructor(new Class[]{})` instead of `forName.getConstructor(null)`. This will get rid of your warning.

So the code without warnings could look like:

```
private final static Class[] EMPTY_PARAM = new Class[]{};

private static boolean checkImpled(Class interfaceClass, Class<?> forName) {
    try {
        if (!Modifier.isAbstract(forName.getModifiers())
                && !forName.isInterface()
                && interfaceClass.isAssignableFrom(forName)
                && !interfaceClass.equals(forName)
                && forName.getConstructor(EMPTY_PARAM) != null) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // false
    }

    return false;
}
```